# how to export data from python pandas with user defined message

Tags: python, pandas

From the pandas data frame, I got the list of customer info and want to export it to an excel printing all the customer info like:

"This customer James"

"This customer Mark"

''''''''

''''''''

but am getting only 1 customer to excel instead of 10.

Below is the code i tried:

```
info = 
df['TABLE'].drop_duplicates().values.tolist()
for i in (Info):
 excel_print= "This customer" ' ' +i
 print(excel_print) ## I will get all 10 customers
 for j in excel_print:
 worksheet.write(1,1,excel_print)
```

Comment: using `for j in excel_print` you gets chars form string, not data from table.

Comment: `write(1,1, ...)` puts to the same cell - you have to use different `rows` or `columns`

Comment: @furas, as long as the loop continues, it has to print in next line automatically

Comment: I don't understand last loop - you get char by char and you print the same string in the same cell. it will not add new text to existing text. It will remove old text.

Comment: Then how to add the total output to excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it in separated cells then you have to change first (or second) argument in `write()`

I use `enumerate()` to have different values

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook   = xlsxwriter.Workbook('filename.xlsx')

worksheet1 = workbook.add_worksheet()

info = ['Adam','James', 'Mark']

for x, name in enumerate(info):
    worksheet1.write(x, 0, "This customer " + name)

workbook.close()
```

If you want all in one cell then you have to create string with all text and then put it

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook   = xlsxwriter.Workbook('filename.xlsx')

worksheet1 = workbook.add_worksheet()

info = ['Adam','James', 'Mark']

lines = []

for name in info:
    lines.append("This customer " + name)

text = '\n'.join(lines)    

worksheet1.write(0, 0, text)

workbook.close()
```

Comment: Yes, this is working fine now..thanks for your help @furas :)

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas .to_excel or .to_csv

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(['tom','harry', 'jack', 'tom', 'jack'], columns =['name'])
print(df.head())
df['name'] = 'The customer ' + df['name'] 
df.drop_duplicates().to_excel('names.xlsx')
```

Output:
[image: names.xlsx]